# Matlab plots 2 tikz. Axis collapse

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, matlab, matlab2tikz

I'm writing my thesis, and it seems I need to convert all my images to `tikz` and include them in my TeX file. I used matlab2tikz command to convert the plots to tikz.

It was not that hard, but there is something I can't explain. In my document I import the next code:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \resizebox {\columnwidth} {!} {

        \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
        \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
        %
        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[...]
        \addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr]{...};
        \addlegendentry{sys}

        \addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr]{...};
        \addlegendentry{sysr}

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[...]
        \addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr]{...};
        \addlegendentry{sys}

        \addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr]{...};
        \addlegendentry{sysr}

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[...]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \caption{Bode response of two systems}
\end{figure}
```

I have two problems:

- The plot is a Bode plot. In the X axis should have written "Frequency (Hz)", and in fact it has. But is overlapped to the units in the X axis. Example in the image:[image: frequency label overlapping with units]
- It shows me error in the `\addlegendentry{}` lines (the 4 of them).

I'm sorry if it's a stupid question. I'm beginner at this and in a rush.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You *need* to? At the end, it all depends on your supervisor and university guidelines. However, you should know that you can import figures in your LaTeX document from different types of files, even vectorial: `.pdf`, `.eps`, etc. It might be an easier solution that still ensure good quality figures (i.e. non raster graphics)